# HTML jump to content by links in nav column

Tags: html, jekyll

in the navigation column on the left of this site:
https://github.com/orderedlist/minimal

(which is implemented as
`<ul>`
          `<li><a href="...`
I would really like to be able to add jump links, so that clicking on one of them scrolls the right column.

That way, on the left, users click on a topic and the part on the right jumps/scrolls to that content. Can this be done without fuzz or hassle (like installing a different theme).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can target the `href` attribute to the section that you want by simply targeting the `id` of the element

for example:

```html
<li><a href="#column2">click me to jump to column 2</a></li>

<div id="column2">section 2</div>
```

Comment: That href will try to load a new page that doesn't exist. It's not how hash anchors work

Comment: @charlietfl omg i forgot to add `#` in front of `column2` xD thanks for noticing that